# What does the question mark mean in `impliedTokenType: ?string`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In Stripe elements,
https://github.com/stripe-archive/react-stripe-elements/blob/99ab31d9188b6b1a12daa1675f8ee434e07ef2cc/src/components/Elements.js#L113

There is a question mark before the type.

I thought the syntax was supposed to `impliedTokenType?: string`, but instead it's `impliedTokenType: ?string`.

What's the difference?

Comment: It's a `.js` file, so it's not typescript. It's the new javascript [type annotations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-type-annotations/blob/master/syntax/grammar-ideas.md#allowed-types).

Comment: maybe [JSDOC nullable type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html#:~:text=Nullable%20type)? 
But afaik JSDOC is not written inline.

Answer (score 1):

`impliedTokenType?: string` means it's optional, so it can be exist in props or you can ignore to pass it.

`impliedTokenType: ?string` means it's not optional, should be passed as props, but it can be null.